# rank of a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I read this sentence in a report concerning in symmetric cone programs: "Let J be a Euclidean Jordan algebra with dimension n, and rank r."  I know what the rank of a (matrix) is.. does the rank here have the same meaning for a vector space, "the maximum number of linearly independent vectors" ?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe you should look up the definition of a symmetric cone: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_cone#Idempotents_and_rank

Comment: You're right.. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of "rank" for a Euclidean Jordan algebra is as follows, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_cone):

Definition: The maximal number of elements in a Jordan frame is called the rank. (Jordan frame has to do with idempotents).